# How to save and return to newly created item in previous page?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5, oracle-apex-5.1

I have an interactive report and a form associated to it. After creating a new entry using the form, my end-users want to put the focus on that specific new entry in the interactive report (it's a lot of entrys, and today they need to scroll down a lot to see the new one).

They also want the same funcionality when updating a row of the report.

How can I do this the correct way in **APEX 5.1**?

Comment: Please show us your efforts

Comment: Why just not put it on the top of report?

Comment: @BorisSerafimov, can't do that, because the report is already sorted by a variable (user requirement).

Comment: @theProgrammer101, tried a couple of things already, like a javascript function on the report page to set focus on the new entry (identified by ID), but couldn't put that to work.

Comment: But you can still have sorting based on that variable. Just last edited will be on top of other. Like 3,1,2,4,5,6...

Comment: @BorisSerafimov, how can I do that?

Comment: Please post some code. If you have none to post, please create an example. See [How Do I Create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

Here is one aproach based on EMP table in **apex.oracle.com** 
Create interactive report with edit form. In my case this is page 6 for report and page 7 for edit. Create one hiden item on page six (P6_EMPNO). Add case to your query so in my example it's look something like:

```
select "ROWID", 
"EMPNO",
"ENAME",
"JOB",
"MGR",
"HIREDATE",
"SAL",
"COMM",
"DEPTNO"
from "#OWNER#"."EMP"
ORDER BY CASE WHEN EMPNO = :P6_EMPNO THEN 1 ELSE 2 END, EMPNO
```

I'm sorting result by EMPNO.

 Choose ***P6_EMPNO*** in **Page Items to Submit** section. Go to page 7, select branch(**Go to page 6**)and click on **Target** In set items section choose **P6_EMPNO** and for target **&P7_EMPNO.**

Now every time you go to page 7, the value of hiden item will be the EMPNO from page 7 and it will apear on top of the region. You can use jQuery to highlight the row and put some validations to update P6_EMPNO only when some data was changed.
I hope this can help you.

Answer (score 0):

easy.

You don't even have to create any additional page items. Change your form DML so that it returns into the primary key page item holder. Then Create a process after your DML process but before the reset cache process. Use APEX_IR API to reset pagination on your IR page, and then set an interactive report filter based on the primary key page item you returned the new PK into. Check the documentation for exact usage.

Apex_IR.reset_report to reset the report pagination and remove any filters.

Apex_ir.add_filter to add a filter = to new primary key

Answer (score 0):

Interesting question, another solution:

- Create a item in your report page, something like **P3_ANCHOR**
- Add ***data-anchor="#< YOUR_COLUMN_ID >#"*** to your report link attribute 
  [image]
- Configure your form page to return the created/modified item id to item **P3_ANCHOR** in your report page.
- Create a Dynamic Action on report page

[image]

- Action: Execute Javascript Code
- Code:

  ```
  var container = $('body'),
      scrollTo = $('[data-anchor="'+$v('P3_ANCHOR')+'"]');

  container.animate({
      scrollTop: scrollTo.offset().top - $(document).scrollTop()
  }, 2000);
  ```

Comment: Hello hmarques.  I tried this in Apex 19.1.  It doesn't seem to work for me.  My IR contains LAST_NAME (first column), FIRST_NAME, PRIM_KEY(hidden), EMAIL, etc.  I can see the P37_Anchor field at the top of the report page.  That field is display-only right now, and it contains the proper Last Name from the edit form.  I modified the DA's Javascript Code to change 'P3_ANCHOR' to 'P37_ANCHOR'  The report just goes to the first Last Name when I return from the edit form.  Have you made this work in Apex 19.1?

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution: 
Sort your report descending so that the last created ID will be the first in the IR